# Clojure thread-first with filter function

Tags: filter, clojure, sqlkorma

I'm having a problem stringing some forms together to do some ETL on a result set from a korma function.

I get back from korma sql:

`({:id 1 :some_field "asd" :children [{:a 1 :b 2 :c 3} {:a 1 :b 3 :c 4} {:a 2 :b 2 :c 3}] :another_field "qwe"})`

I'm looking to filter this result set by getting the "children" where the `:a` keyword is 1.

My attempt:

```
;mock of korma result
(def data '({:id 1 :some_field "asd" :children [{:a 1 :b 2 :c 3} {:a 1 :b 3 :c 4} {:a 2 :b 2 :c 3}] :another_field "qwe"}))

(-> data 
    first 
    :children 
    (filter #(= (% :a) 1)))
```

What I'm expecting here is a vector of hashmaps that :a is set to 1, i.e :

```
[{:a 1 :b 2 :c 3} {:a 1 :b 3 :c 4}]
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: xxx.core$eval3145$fn__3146  clojure.lang.RT.seqFrom (RT.java:505)
```

From the error I gather it's trying to create a sequence from a function...though just not able to connect the dots as to why.

Further, if I separate the filter function entirely by doing the following:

```
(let [children (-> data first :children)] 
    (filter #(= (% :a) 1) children))
```

it works. I'm not sure why the first-thread is not applying the filter function, passing in the `:children` vector as the coll argument.

Any and all help much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want the `thread-last` macro:

```
(->> data first :children (filter #(= (% :a) 1)))
```

yields

({:a 1, :b 2, :c 3} {:a 1, :b 3, :c 4})

The `thread-first` macro in your original code is equivalent to writing:

```
(filter (:children (first data)) #(= (% :a) 1))
```

Which results in an error, because your anonymous function is not a sequence.

Answer (score 3):

The thread-first (`->`) and thread-last (`->>`) macros are always problematical in that it is easy to make a mistake in choosing one over the other (or in mixing them up as you have done here).  Break down the steps like so:

```
(ns tstclj.core
  (:use cooljure.core)  ; see https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/
  (:gen-class))

(def data [ {:id 1 :some_field "asd" 
             :children [ {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3} 
                          {:a 1 :b 3 :c 4}
                          {:a 2 :b 2 :c 3} ] 
             :another_field "qwe"} ] )

(def v1    (first data))
(def v2    (:children v1))
(def v3    (filter #(= (% :a) 1) v2))

(spyx v1)    ; from tupelo.core/spyx
(spyx v2)
(spyx v3)
```

You will get results like:

```
v1 => {:children [{:c 3, :b 2, :a 1} {:c 4, :b 3, :a 1} {:c 3, :b 2, :a 2}], :another_field "qwe", :id 1, :some_field "asd"}
v2 => [{:c 3, :b 2, :a 1} {:c 4, :b 3, :a 1} {:c 3, :b 2, :a 2}]
v3 => ({:c 3, :b 2, :a 1} {:c 4, :b 3, :a 1})
```

which is what you desired.  The problem is that you really needed to use thread-last for the `filter` form.  The most reliable way of avoiding this problem is to always be explicit and use the Clojure `as->` threading form, or, even better, `it->` from [the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo):

```
(def result (it-> data 
                  (first it)
                  (:children  it)
                  (filter #(= (% :a) 1) it)))
```

By using thread-first, you accidentally wrote the equivalent of this:

```
(def result (it-> data 
                  (first it)
                  (:children  it)
                  (filter it #(= (% :a) 1))))
```

and the error reflects the fact that the function `#(= (% :a) 1)` can't be cast into a seq.  Sometimes, it pays to use a `let` form and give names to the intermediate results:

```
(let [result-map        (first data)
      children-vec      (:children  result-map)
      a1-maps           (filter #(= (% :a) 1) children-vec) ]
  (spyx a1-maps))
;;-> a1-maps => ({:c 3, :b 2, :a 1} {:c 4, :b 3, :a 1})
```

We could also look at either of the two previous solutions and notice that the output of each stage is used as the *last* argument to the next function in the pipeline.  Thus, we could also solve it with thread-last:

```
(def result3  (->>  data
                    first
                    :children
                    (filter #(= (% :a) 1))))
(spyx result3)
;;-> result3 => ({:c 3, :b 2, :a 1} {:c 4, :b 3, :a 1})
```

Unless your processing chain is very simple, I find it is just about always clearer to use the `it->` form to be explicit about how the intermediate value should be used by each stage of the pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure why the first-thread is not applying the filter function, passing in the :children vector as the coll argument.

This is precisely what the `thread-first` macro does.

From the [clojuredocs.org](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E):

> Threads the expr through the forms. Inserts x as the
>   second item in the first form, making a list of it if it is not a
>   list already.

So, in your case the application of `filter` ends up being:

`(filter [...] #(= (% :a) 1))`

If you *must* use `thread-first` (instead of `thread-last`), then you can get around this by partially applying `filter` and its predicate:

```
(->
  data
  first
  :children
  ((partial filter #(= (:a %) 1)))
  vec)

; [{:a 1, :b 2, :c 3} {:a 1, :b 3, :c 4}]
```